# Catch NoSuch Element with log.error in webdriver?

Tags: java, design-patterns, selenium, logging, try-catch

I added log4j(apache software) as logger to my webdriver testing.

I wonder if log.error statements **should be put in catch block as good practice**?

Are not we supposed to use exception e object and just work with e like this:
 e.printStackTrace()?

**Is it a proper practice to add log.error into catch block?**

```
​public static WebElement destinationTextBox(WebDdriver driver){    
try{    
element = driver.findElement(by...) ;  //this can raise exception if no element found  
}
//it will be caught here
catch(NoSuchElementException e){    
log.error( "no element found") ;
}

// if element found and no exception, just log 'element found'
log.info(Destination text box element found) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? But it's better to provide original exception along with the message e.g. `log.error("Message", e);`

Answer (score 0):

Logging is indeed a good idea in case of production code. However, since you've mentioned that this is a test code I would suggest to catch a checked exception and rethrow it as an unchecked one:

```
catch(NoSuchElementException e){    
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This way you wouldn't need to investigate any log files for a possible test failure but your test framework will explicitly tell you about a problem if any.